# Deploying multi-stage Docker image in Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, docker-image

I created a multi-stage Docker image to reduce the size of my python application. The content of the Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim AS image-compiling

# updates pip and prepare for installing wheels
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install wheel && \
    pip cache purge

# install needed modules from wheels
RUN pip install --user \
  Flask==2.2.2 Flask-RESTful==0.3.9 Flask-Cors==3.0.10 keras==2.9.0 && \
    pip cache purge

# brand new image
FROM python:3.10-slim AS image-deploy

# get python 'user environment'
COPY --from=image-compiling /root/.local /root/.local

# get app content
COPY app ./app

# define working directory and the standard command (run it detached)
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["wsgi.py"]
```

Then I pushed the image `my_image` to the Google Cloud Storage of my project `my_proj` with:

```
$ docker push us.gcr.io/my_proj/my_image
```

When I try to start a Google Cloud Run service with this image, it fails with the Python error:

```
Error   2022-09-14 11:41:13.744 EDTTraceback (most recent call last): File "/app/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module> from flask import render_template ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
Warning 2022-09-14 11:41:13.805 EDTContainer called exit(1).
```

But `flask` is installed in the image, and a container created locally from this image does run it normally.

Why the container in Google Cloud Run is not able to find the module `flask`?
Isn't it created completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason of the problem:**

The problem in this case is not with the fact that the image was created using the multi-stage approach. The issue is that the Python modules were installed using the option `--user`.

This option was included so that the needed Python modules were stored in the folder `/root/.local`, which could be copied directly to the new *deploy* image.

However, for some reason, Python applications in containers in Google Cloud Run are not able to find the modules if they are in the folder `/root/.local`. Probably a user other than `root` is used there. Thus, using the `--user` argument of `pip` does not work, which also inhibits the multi-stage approach in this type of scenario.

**Solution:**

Do a "mono-stage" image with global Python modules, i.e., a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

# updates pip and prepare for installing wheels
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install wheel && \
    pip cache purge

# install needed modules from wheels
RUN pip install \
      Flask==2.2.2 Flask-RESTful==0.3.9 Flask-Cors==3.0.10 keras==2.9.0 && \
    pip cache purge

# get app content
COPY app ./app

# define working directory and the standard command (run it detached)
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["wsgi.py"]
```